# Install Win 10 directly using usb when Ubuntu already installed and run into grub?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, grub

I previously have Ubuntu installed on my PC(**not** dual boot).

Now I want to overwrite it and install Win 10 so I use usb to install Win 10 directly.

However, in the process of installing Win 10, it seems the install manager want to reboot and then it ran into grub.

I don't know anything about grub, how can I have my PC installed with Win 10 now?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way, as you do not want to keep Ubuntu is to do a Custom Installation of Windows 10.
This will give you the opportunity to remove all previously created partitions.
Just install Windows on the non-partitionned hard drive.

If grub is still there, override the default boot option on your BIOS/UEFI manager.